# How to get response message from server on Store.sync()

Tags: json, extjs

I have a store which I'd like to `sync()` with server.

`Store.sync()` method have `success` and `failure` property-functions, they have `Ext.data.Batch` and `options` as parameters.

If I get such response from server:

```
{
  success: false,
  msg: "test error!"
}
```

`failure` method invokes.

How to access response `msg` property from within `failure` method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    store.sync({
        failure: function(batch, options) {
            alert(batch.proxy.getReader().jsonData.msg);
        }
    });
```

Comment: `jsonData` reader's property is deprecated
**deprecated Will be removed in Ext JS 5.0. This is just a copy of this.rawData - use that instead.**
Indeed they removed the `jsonData` in 5th version.

Comment: @Vlad `batch.proxy.getReader().jsonData` contains the response for the last operation in the batch. 
Having proxy with default configuration `batchActions = true` and `batchOrder = 'create,update,destroy'` and batch (`Ext.data.Batch` default configuration `pauseOnException = false`) with create and update operations, if create operation failed but the update operation succeeded, then the reader's `rawData` would have the success message.

Answer (score 2):

> Store.sync() method have success and failure property-functions, they have Ext.data.Batch and options as parameters.

Any failed operations collecting inside `batch.exceptions` array. It has all what you need.
Just go through the failed operations, processing them.

Operation failure message ("test error!") would be inside - **operation.error**

```
store.sync({
    failure: function(batch, options) {
        Ext.each(batch.exceptions, function(operation) {
            if (operation.hasException()) {
                Ext.log.warn('error message: ' + operation.error);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Proxy set it inside [processResponse](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Server-method-processResponse) method:

```
operation.setException(result.message);
```

Where:

- Operation's [setException](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Operation-method-setException) method sets its `error` property (error message there).
- `result` is [Ext.data.ResultSet](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.ResultSet) and the `result.message` if filled by the proxy's reader, using the reader's `messageProperty`

But, by default reader's message property is `messageProperty: 'message'`. 
In your case you should configured the reader with correct messageProperty, like:

```
reader: {
    ...
    messageProperty: 'msg'
}
```

or return from the server response with `metadata` configuration property, like:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "msg": "test error!", 
    "metaData": {
        ...
        "messageProperty": 'msg'
    }
}
```

[Json reader - Response MetaData (docs section)](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Json)