# How to add sync callbacks to store in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6-classic, extjs6.2

I have a store which I want to sync manually everytime certain actions are done.

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16035501/how-to-get-response-message-from-server-on-store-sync) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35226480/extjs-6-access-messageproperty-in-store-syncs-callback) too.

What I'd like to know is if there is a way to establish a default sync callback functions on the store configurations.

I know I can do something like this:

```
store.sync({
        success: function(batch, options) {
            console.log('ok');
        },
        failure: function(batch, options) {
            console.log('not ok');
        }
    });
```

But I want to define the callbacks one time in the store itself and then I would just call store.sync();

Here is an example of the store I'm working with:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.MyStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.MyStore',
    model: 'MyApp.model.MyModel',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: '../../api/myEndPoint',
        noCache: false,
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'data',
            successProperty: 'success',
            totalProperty: 'total'
        },
        actionMethods: {
            read: 'GET',
            destroy: 'DELETE'
        },
        extraParams: {
            type: 'aux'
        }
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is a way to achieve what you want through the means of the Framework I could not find it.

There is always another option, you can wrap the sync in to a function and call that function every time you want to sync with these particular callbacks:

```
function sync({
    success = (batch, options) => console.log('ok'),
    failure = (batch, options) => console.log('not ok')
} = {}) {
    store.sync({success, failure});
}
```

You can change the default functions in parameters by passing in parameters:

```
// default paramters will be used
sync();

// just one parameter
sync({
  failure: () => {
    console.log('new failure handler');
  }
});

// both parameters
sync({
  success: () => {
    console.log('new success handler');
  },
  failure: () => {
    console.log('new failure handler');
  }
});
```

Consider that if the default callbacks for the store will ever be implemented this solution would likely be considered a "hack". Going to the frameworks own solution would be a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this issue with an override of the store's **sync** method.

Sync is basically calling the proxy's **batch** method that supports success and failure callbacks. So if you set for example syncSuccess and syncFailure callbacks in your store, they will be called only after syncing the store.

Notes:

- I tested the solution on version 7.1.0. Check for differences in the sync methods for your version
- You need to add extra logic for the case when the callbacks are not defined on the store

```
Ext.define('Overrides.data.Store', {
    override: 'Ext.data.Store',

    sync: function(options) {
        var me = this,
            operations = {},
            toCreate = me.getNewRecords(),
            toUpdate = me.getUpdatedRecords(),
            toDestroy = me.getRemovedRecords(),
            needsSync = false;

        //<debug>
        if (me.isSyncing) {
            Ext.log.warn('Sync called while a sync operation is in progress. ' +
                         'Consider configuring autoSync as false.');
        }
        //</debug>

        me.needsSync = false;

        if (toCreate.length > 0) {
            operations.create = toCreate;
            needsSync = true;
        }

        if (toUpdate.length > 0) {
            operations.update = toUpdate;
            needsSync = true;
        }

        if (toDestroy.length > 0) {
            operations.destroy = toDestroy;
            needsSync = true;
        }

        if (needsSync && me.fireEvent('beforesync', operations) !== false) {
            me.isSyncing = true;

            options = options || {};

            me.proxy.batch(Ext.apply(options, {
                operations: operations,
                listeners: me.getBatchListeners(),
                $destroyOwner: me,
                success: me.syncSuccess,
                failure: me.syncFailure
            }));
        }

        return me;
    }
});
```